# There is disrupt convert date during transformation java-object (dto) in Json When I customize addCorsMappings()

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-mvc

We need customize global configuration that describes the setting cors-header for requests.

I use SpringBoot and a project is spring bootpackaged in file extention *.war.

```java
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class App
        extends SpringBootServletInitializer
        implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER  = LoggerFactory.getLogger( App.class );

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LOGGER.info("Start an application...");

        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {

        LOGGER.info("There is building the web application!");

        return builder.sources(App.class);
    }
}
```

This is the settitng for cors-header.
I must import the Spring MVC configuration (**@EnableWebMvc**), that the configuration that i have set work.

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class CorsGlobalConfiguration {

 private final static String ROOT_API = "/**";

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfig(){

        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping(ROOT_API)
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET","POST","PUT");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

But a Client have gotten a json in date that  come in array.

For exmaple:

A client must get:

**"2020-03-14T11:32:33",**

But a client is getting

**[2020, 03, 14, 11, 32, 33]**

**Update_1**

I did.

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper configureObjectMapper() {
        JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
        objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

It don't work.

[image]

**Update_2**

I did.

```java
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS = false
```

It don't work.

**Update_3**

```java
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

and

```java
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS = false
```

It also don't work.

[image]

**Update_4**

I performed the following actions;

- application.properties

```java
#spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false
```

```java
@Component
public class JacksonLocalDateSerializer extends StdSerializer<LocalDateTime> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7880057299936771237L;

    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter =
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
                    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

    public JacksonLocalDateSerializer(Class<LocalDateTime> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    public JacksonLocalDateSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(formatter.format(value));
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {


    private JacksonLocalDateSerializer jacksonLocalDateSerializer;

    @Autowired
    public JacksonConfig(JacksonLocalDateSerializer jacksonLocalDateSerializer) {
        this.jacksonLocalDateSerializer = jacksonLocalDateSerializer;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper configureObjectMapper() {

        JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
        javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, this.jacksonLocalDateSerializer);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
        objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);

        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

- dto

```java
...
  private LocalDateTime statusDate;
...
```

I get:

[image]

Why is it so?

How do it correct?

Who has any ideas ?

**Update_5**

I refused to use the @EnableWebMvc annotation.

My the configuration class is now:

```java
@Configuration
public class CorsGlobalConfiguration {

    @Value("${api.prefix}")
    private String apiPrefix;

    @Value("${header.cors.origins.allow}")
    private String [] headerCorsOriginsAllow;

    @Value("${header.cors.methods.allow}")
    private String [] headerCorsMethodsAllow;

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfig() {

        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping(apiPrefix)
                        .allowedOrigins(headerCorsOriginsAllow)
                        .allowedMethods(headerCorsMethodsAllow);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The problem had solved.

Answer (score 1):

Add `jackson-datatype-jsr310` to your dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId></artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Then add below property to your `application.properties` file:

`spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS = false`

Answer (score 1):

If you add `@EnableWebMvc` then by default `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` is enabled
So, configure the Jackson Object Mapper manually to disable this.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public ObjectMapper configureObjectMapper() {
    JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    return objectMapper;
  }
}
```

or

change it in `application.properties`

```
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS = false
```

You can also add your own Serializer class using this line (e.g `JacksonLocalDateSerializer`)

```
javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new JacksonLocalDateSerializer());
```

Example : Here I need show as format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

```
public class JacksonLocalDateSerializer extends StdSerializer<LocalDate> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -7880057299936771237L;

  private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter =
      DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
      .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

  public JacksonLocalDateSerializer() {
    this(null);
  }

  public JacksonLocalDateSerializer(Class<LocalDate> type) {
    super(type);
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(LocalDate value, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
      SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    jsonGenerator.writeString(formatter.format(value));
  }
}
```

Comment: javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new JacksonLocalDateSerializer()); - Can you show example ? Where must it be?

Comment: If you need  your own format to show then it must, I added an example

Comment: I wrote a decision above.

Comment: Yes that I said using `@EnableWebMvc` is the problem. If you don't use it will be okay. If you want to solve using it, I give a solution